# user input followed by fingerprint validation android

Tags: android, validation, android-fingerprint-api

I want to do an app in which it asks for the aadhar number validates the number and verifies the user's fingerprint. I have checked the dummy aadhar number validation and fingerprint validation separately, it works fine. But if I want to integrate them both it is not working in desired way.

here is the code:

```
public class MainActivityAadharNumber extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView, Button.OnClickListener, AadharEnterAmountView {
//copied variables
private KeyStore keyStore;
// Variable used for storing the key in the Android Keystore container
private static final String KEY_NAME = "androidHive";
private Cipher cipher;
boolean fingerprintResult = false;
boolean amountNumberSuccess = false;
private AadharPresenterImpl aadharPresenter;
private PresenterAadharAmountImplementation aadharPresenterImpl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aadhar_input);
    aadharPresenter = new AadharPresenterImpl(this);
    aadharPresenterImpl = new PresenterAadharAmountImplementation(this);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    fingerprintValidation();

    // fingerprint validation function to validate the fingerprint
    //fingerprintValidation();

}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }


    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }


    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}




/**
 * This function performs the validation check with the presenter when the submit button is clicked
 * @param v
 */

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

 if(validateAmountAndAadhar()  )
 {
     //Toast.makeText(this, "fingerprint enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //fingerprintValidation();
     //if(fingerprintResult)
      //

     startActivity(new Intent(this,AuthSuccessActivity.class));
     }
     else{
     Toast.makeText(this, "fingerprint error & amount error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }

@Override
public void showValidationError() {
    //show validationError message
    Toast.makeText(this, "check for the addhar number correctness", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onValidationSuccess() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Aadhar validated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onCorrectAmount() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "correct amount entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void inValidAmount() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "check the amount entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "back press not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public boolean validateAmountAndAadhar()
{
    EditText aadharNumber, aadharAmount;
    TextInputLayout aadharAmountTextInputLayout, aadharNumberTextInputLayout;
    //ImageView initialFingerPrintImage;


    aadharNumber = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.aadharnumberAnimatededitText);
    aadharAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aadharAmountAnimatededitText);
    aadharNumberTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.aadhar_number_TextView_id);
    aadharNumberTextInputLayout.setHint("aadhar number");
    aadharAmountTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.aadhar_amount_TextView_id);
    aadharAmountTextInputLayout.setHint("amount");
    // initialFingerPrintImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_finger_print);

    boolean aadharValidatedNumber = aadharPresenter.aadharNumberValidator(aadharNumber.getText().toString());
    boolean aadharAmountValidator = aadharPresenterImpl.aadharAmountValidator(aadharAmount.getText().toString());
    if (aadharValidatedNumber && aadharAmountValidator ) {
        amountNumberSuccess = true;
        aadharAmountTextInputLayout.setError(null);
        aadharNumberTextInputLayout.setError(null);

    return true;

    }
    // initialFingerPrintImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.finger_print_success);
    //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityFingerPrint.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
    else {
        // multiple IF-else block to catch the possible error outcomes

        if (!aadharAmountValidator && aadharValidatedNumber ) {
            Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
            aadharAmount.startAnimation(shake);
            aadharNumberTextInputLayout.setError(null);
            aadharAmountTextInputLayout.setError("enter the correct amount");
        } else {
            if (aadharAmountValidator && !aadharValidatedNumber) {
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
                aadharNumber.startAnimation(shake);
                aadharAmountTextInputLayout.setError(null);
                aadharNumberTextInputLayout.setError("enter correct Aadhar");
            } else {
                if (!aadharAmountValidator && !aadharValidatedNumber) {
                    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
                    aadharNumber.startAnimation(shake);
                    aadharAmount.startAnimation(shake);
                    aadharAmountTextInputLayout.setError("enter correct amount");
                    aadharNumberTextInputLayout.setError("enter correct aadhar");

                }
            }
        }
        // initialFingerPrintImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.finger_print_failure);
        // Toast.makeText(this,"cannot start the activity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }


}
public void fingerprintValidation()
{


        //begining of the code copu
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        TextView textView;

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        // Check whether the device has a Fingerprint sensor.
        if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
            /**
             * An error message will be displayed if the device does not contain the fingerprint hardware.
             * However if you plan to implement a default authentication method,
             * you can redirect the user to a default authentication activity from here.
             * Example:
             * Intent intent = new Intent(this, DefaultAuthenticationActivity.class);
             * startActivity(intent);
             */
            textView.setText("Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor");


        } else {
            // Checks whether fingerprint permission is set on manifest
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                textView.setText("Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled");
            } else {
                // Check whether at least one fingerprint is registered
                if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                    textView.setText("Register at least one fingerprint in Settings");
                } else {
                    // Checks whether lock screen security is enabled or not
                    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
                        textView.setText("Lock screen security not enabled in Settings");
                    } else {
                        generateKey();


                        if (cipherInit()) {
                            if (amountNumberSuccess) {
                                FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                                FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                                helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                                fingerprintResult = true;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

}

}
```

In this I want to enter the amount, aadhar number;If both are correct then I want to listen to user's fingerprint. On successful validation of these it must redirect to next page. Kindly help me with it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to it the answer is so simple in the FingerprintHandler class create a static variable mfingerprintAuth = false, and inside the onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) method define  a  mfingerprintAuth = true, get it in the mainActivity like FingerprintHandler.mfingerprintAuth and do the necessary check.